# Proof about quotient map

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0, \infty)$ defined as $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is a quotient map. I proved that $f$ is onto and continuous. But I have problems proving if $f^{-1} (U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $U$ is open in $[0, \infty]$ where $U \subset [0, \infty)$. And also I tried proving that $f$ is open map taking a basis element $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ and see that $f((a,b) \times (c,d))$ is open in $[0, \infty)$. I need an idea

Comment: What is the image of some basic ball in $R^2$, say $B(0,1)$

Comment: @SebastianCor I think that is $[0,1)$

Comment: Is $[0,1)$ open?

Comment: $[0,1)=(-1,1) \cap [0,\infty)$

Comment: And I think that is open

Comment: Hence for a basic open set $B$, from which every open set is generated by definition of basis of a topology, we have that $f(B)$ is open in $[0,\infty)$ and hence your function is open.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a \geq 0$ and $c \geq 0$. Then the image of $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ under $f$ is the interval $(a^2+c^2,b^2+d^2)$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is closed: it is a proper and continuous function to a $T_2$ and compactly generated set.
It is proper since if $K\subset[0,\infty) $ is compact, $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed as counter image of a closed set, and it is limited since surely $f^{-1}(K)\subset f^{-1}(\max K) \subset B(0,(\max K) ^2)$.

Anyway if you want to follow your strategy, you can observe that $f$ is the squared Euclidean norm and $f(B(x, r))=((|| x||-r)^2,(||x||+r)^2)$ if $||x||\ge r$, $[0,(||x||+r)^2)$ if   $||x||<r$, so $f$ is open.

Comment: In my topology course we haven't studiedaba about compactly generated set. yet

Comment: About compactness?

Comment: No, we haven't studied compactness